# adding font to mPDF

Tags: php, fonts, mpdf

I'm getting the following error when I try and generate a PDF using the mPDF class:

```
TTF file "C:/wamp/www/inc/mpdf/ttfonts/verdana.ttf": invalid checksum 20f65173c11 table: DSIG (expected 65173c11)
```

I've uploaded the font files to my `ttfonts` directory and defined the font in `config_fonts.php` like this:

```
"verdana" => array(
    'R' => "verdana.ttf",
    'B' => "verdanab.ttf",
    'I' => "verdanai.ttf",
    'BI' => "verdanaz.ttf",
    ),
```

I only see the error when I turn on font error reporting in the config settings. When I turn error reporting off, the PDF is generated, but the font being used is not Verdana.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have any success?

Comment: check this link http://www.mpdf1.com/forum/discussion/1139/fonts-not-showing/p1

Answer (score 28):

Following are the steps to add new font family in mpdf library:

1. Download the font zip and unzip it.
2. Add new `newFont.ttf` font file(s) to this location `/mpdf/ttfonts` folder.
3. Edit `/mpdf/config_fonts.php` OR `/mpdf/src/config/FontVariables.php` to add an entry to the `$this->fontdata` array for the new font file(s). Like:

   ```
   $this->fontdata = array(
       "newFont" => array(
       'R' => "newFont-Regular.ttf",
       'B' => "newFont-Bold.ttf",
       'I' => "newFont-Italic.ttf",
       'BI' => "newFont-BoldItalic.ttf",
   ),
   ```
4. `font-family: 'newFont';` is now available in the stylesheets.
5. `$mpdfObj = new mPDF('', '', 'newFont');
    $mpdfObj->SetFont('newFont');`
6. Now your new font is added.

Comment: I strongly advise against the method described here. Under no circumstances should you change the original files - all changes are gone with the update. Here is how to do it in the original documentation: https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html

Answer (score 22):

Based on @hrvoje-golcic answer, here's an improved and less dirty way to add fonts to mPDF without editing `config_fonts.php`. I'm using Laravel, I installed mPDF using composer.

1. As suggested by the author, define a constant named `_MPDF_TTFONTPATH` before initializing `mPDF` with the value as the path to your `ttfonts` folder (this constant exists since at least 5.3).
2. Copy the `vendor/mpdf/mpdf/ttfonts` folder to a location that you control (outside of the vendor folder).
3. Add your custom fonts to that folder along with the others.
4. Add your configuration to the `fontdata` property on the `mPDF` instance.

> **Heads up**: The `ttfonts` folder has around 90MB so there's still might be a better way, but you have to copy all the fonts since the original config adds them. See composer script alternative at the bottom of this answer.
>
> **IMPORTANT:** [CSS font-family will be transformed](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/font-names.html) to lowercase + nospaces so "Source Sans Pro" will become sourcesanspro.

Here's an example:

```
if (!defined('_MPDF_TTFONTPATH')) {
    // an absolute path is preferred, trailing slash required:
    define('_MPDF_TTFONTPATH', realpath('fonts/'));
    // example using Laravel's resource_path function:
    // define('_MPDF_TTFONTPATH', resource_path('fonts/'));
}

function add_custom_fonts_to_mpdf($mpdf, $fonts_list) {

    $fontdata = [
        'sourcesanspro' => [
            'R' => 'SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf',
            'B' => 'SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf',
        ],
    ];

    foreach ($fontdata as $f => $fs) {
        // add to fontdata array
        $mpdf->fontdata[$f] = $fs;

        // add to available fonts array
        foreach (['R', 'B', 'I', 'BI'] as $style) {
            if (isset($fs[$style]) && $fs[$style]) {
                // warning: no suffix for regular style! hours wasted: 2
                $mpdf->available_unifonts[] = $f . trim($style, 'R');
            }
        }

    }

    $mpdf->default_available_fonts = $mpdf->available_unifonts;
}

$mpdf = new mPDF('UTF-8', 'A4');
add_custom_fonts_to_mpdf($mpdf);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

### Composer post-install script

Instead of copying all the fonts and adding them to git, a handy workaround using a composer post-install script can do that for you.

First of all, make sure the folder where you wish to copy the fonts exists, and create a `.gitignore` in it, with the following contents:

```
*
!.gitignore
!SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
!SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf
```

This will ignore everything except the `.gitignore` file and the fonts you wish to add.

Next, add the following scripts to your `composer.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "cp -f vendor/mpdf/mpdf/ttfonts/* resources/fonts/"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "cp -f vendor/mpdf/mpdf/ttfonts/* resources/fonts/"
    ]
}
```

### Notes

This was tested to work with 6.1.
In 7.x, the author [implemented](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/146) an elegant way to add external fonts.

Comment: This might be the correct way of adding custom fonts but... if you are using **Laravel and mPDF 7.x**  the simplest way is mentioned here [adding custom fonts in mPDF 7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586409/adding-font-to-mpdf/54586897#54586897)

Comment: Well the problem is that it is very wrong to manually change stuff in the `vendor` folder

Comment: Ah ah so funny I could not find the lowercase conversion anywhere in the docs. Why did they do it and why why why not document it with a big red giant huge blinking disclaimer in the custom font section? Thank tou @s3v3n.

Answer (score 6):

There is another "dirty" way to add fonts dynamically in the run-time aside to the lib files. This was my solution because I wasn't able to modify `config_fonts.pdf` file since it was in vendor/ files and would be overwritten on library update.

```
function add_custom_fonts_to_mpdf($mpdf, $fonts_list) {
    // Logic from line 1146 mpdf.pdf - $this->available_unifonts = array()...       
    foreach ($fonts_list as $f => $fs) {
        // add to fontdata array
        $mpdf->fontdata[$f] = $fs;

        // add to available fonts array
        if (isset($fs['R']) && $fs['R']) { $mpdf->available_unifonts[] = $f; }
        if (isset($fs['B']) && $fs['B']) { $mpdf->available_unifonts[] = $f.'B'; }
        if (isset($fs['I']) && $fs['I']) { $mpdf->available_unifonts[] = $f.'I'; }
        if (isset($fs['BI']) && $fs['BI']) { $mpdf->available_unifonts[] = $f.'BI'; }
    }
    $mpdf->default_available_fonts = $mpdf->available_unifonts;
}
```

> Make sure to provide font paths relative to to mpdf's `ttfonts/` dir
>
> **IMPORTANT:** CSS font-family will be transformed to lowercase + nospaces so "Source Sans Pro-Regular" will become sourcesanspro-regular

For example here I'm adding 2 fonts and 3 font files because other font has regular and bold version:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', '', '', 20, 15, 50, 25, 10, 10);
$custom_fontdata = array(
    'sourcesanspro-regular' => array(
        'R' => "../../../../wms/hr_frontend/job/internet/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf" 
        // use 'R' to support CSS font-weight: normal
        // use 'B', 'I', 'BI' and etc. to support CSS font-weight: bold, font-style: italic, and both...
    ),
    'someotherfont' => array(
        'R' => "../../../../wms/hr_frontend/job/internet/fonts/someotherfont.ttf", // In CSS font-weight: normal
        'B' => "../../../../wms/hr_frontend/job/internet/fonts/someotherfont-bold.ttf" // In CSS font-weight: bold
    )
);
add_custom_font_to_mpdf($mpdf, $custom_fontdata);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

This was for mpdf 5.x but hopefully it works for 6.x as well. Did anyone try?

Comment: I can confirm this worked for the 6.x branch of mPDF. Thanks for suggesting this, I have no idea why all that logic is baked into the initial setup of mpdf and can't be rerun outside of it ಠ_ಠ It would solve a lot of problems with fonts! :)

Answer (score 2):

simply add font to FontVariable.php

```
                "pacifico" => [
                'R' => "Pacifico.ttf",
                'useOTL' => 0xFF,
                'useKashida' => 75,
            ],
```

make sure if the ttf file name is start with capital letter like **Pacifico.ttf** then name the font family with start of small letter as i do on top .
e.g make this **pacifico** 
and now simply test this with create testing php file

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];
$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
'mode' => 'utf-8',
'format' => 'A4'.('orientation' == 'L' ? '-L' : ''),
'orientation' => 0,
'margin_left' => 3,
'margin_right' => 3,
'margin_top' => 3,
'margin_bottom' => 0,
'margin_header' => 0,
'margin_footer' => 0,
]);    
$texttt= '
    <html>
    <p style="font-family: dejavusanscondensed;"> Text in Frutiger </p>
    <p style="font-family: freeserif;"> Text in Frutiger </p>
    <p style="font-family: freemono;"> Text in Frutiger </p>
    <p style="font-family: freeserif;"> مرحبا بالعالم </p>
    <p style="font-family: unbatang;"> 하는 바에 의하여 영장제도 </p>
    <p style="font-family: centurygothic;"> Text in Frutiger </p>
    <p style="font-family: pacifico;"> Text in Frutiger </p>
    <p style="font-family: windsong;"> Text in Frutiger </p>
    </html>';
     $mpdf->WriteHTML($texttt,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to show errors on the screen.
See all errors and warnings in log file like "error.log" of your php + apache(?) server.
It help you to find and resolve the problem based on message in the log file.

I any case you should use recommend fonts - see mPDF manual.

Probably, you need to convert TrueType fonts into proper MPDF's format. (http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=409&searchstring=fonts)

Answer (score 0):

Mpdf add Arial font

1. Download font file : https://github.com/JotJunior/PHP-Boleto-ZF2/blob/master/public/assets/fonts/arial.ttf
2. Paste the arial.ttf to mpdf/ttfonts
3. Open config_fonts.php and the below code with fontdata array

   "arial" => array(
       'R' => "arial.ttf",
       ),