# mpdf can't add new font-family helvetica-neue-condensed-black

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, mpdf

I'm using mPdf version 6 and want to add new custom font in it but it's not using new font family. What I did is:

- mpdf\ttfonts folder
- in config_fonts.php file added following code in fontdata:

  "helvetica" => array(
      'R' => "helvetica-neue-condensed-black-59233f88d5395.ttf",
  ),

where "helvetica-neue-condensed-black-59233f88d5395.ttf" is the name of the file.

Following is my mPdf code for creating pdf:

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf(['mode' => 'c']);
    $mpdf->SetFont('helvetica');
    $mpdf->SetTitle('PDF title');
    $mpdf->AddPage('P','','','','',8,8,5,5,10,10);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->html);
    $mpdf->Output('test.pdf', 'd');
```

I checked whatever I write in SetFont nothing in Pdf changed..

Comment: Anything from the error log? Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586409/adding-font-to-mpdf

Answer (score 0):

As from the mpdf docs

> 1. Core non-embedded fontsPermalink
>
> PDF files have certain standard fonts: Helvetica, Times and Courier in
>   the win-1252 character set, and  Zapfdingbats and Symbol character
>   sets. These fonts should be available to any PDF reading program, and
>   do not need to be embedded in the PDF document.
>
> Advantages: Small file size, fast processing, small memory usage.
>
> Disadvantages: Limited choice of fonts for appearance. Will not
>   display characters which are not in the win-1252 Symbols, or Dingbats
>   codepages (suitable for most Western European languages).
>
> To use core fonts only, use 'c' for the mode configuration key:

`$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'c']);`

Change the mode from c to something else.