# MPDF, glyphicons not working (php codeigniter)

Tags: php, mpdf

I am trying to convert a html page to pdf using MPDF. In the page i am having some glyphicons. The page is converted to pdf without glyphicons.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are "glyphicons"? Are they realized through a special font that you have not yet added to mPDF (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586409/adding-font-to-mpdf for that)?

Comment: @Nico Haase FYI, this is glyphicons
http://glyphicons.com/

Comment: See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549328/glyphicon-error-when-using-mpdf-to-export-data/49551034#49551034 and possibly upvote so this can be marked as a duplicate question

Comment: @finwe Not like fontawesome.... Adding bootstrap like .glyphicon-play-circle:before {
  content: "\e029";
} then use this class in MPDF..