# Glyphicon / FontAwesome not showing in mPDF HTML export

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mPDF and when exporting HTML content to pdf, all contents are showing perfectly. But `glyphicons` are not showing. So I add font awesome style code in `/application/third_party/mpdf/config_fonts.php` as follows

```
"fontawesome" => array(  
    'R' => "fontawesome-webfont.ttf"  
 ),
```

And changed the code in view page

```
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
```

to

```
<span style="font-family: fontawesome;">&#xf095;</span>
```

After doing that I got `fontawesome` inside pdf.
Is there any way to use

```
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
```

to generate icon inside pdf?

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing together Font Awesome and Glyphicons, which are different projects.

Anyway, both use `::before` CSS pseudoclass to display element content with the actual icon and this pseudoclass is **not supported** in mPDF.

That means there is no way to display those icons without pre-processing the HTML (adding content to `i` with `fa` class) or inserting characters directly as you have shown in your example.

```
<span style="font-family: fontawesome;">&#xf095;</span>
```

Comment: Is pseudoclass supported in fpdf or tcpdf  library ?

Comment: I don't think so.